# Compare the height of arguments

Tags: macros, formatting, conditionals, xifthen

I'm trying to define a `\newcommand` with three arguments. I'd like to:

- compare the height of these arguments
- choose the largest height to create frames (with that height) around the arguments.

**Question**

How can I compare these three arguments to choose the *tallest*?

---

### First Update

Following the advise by *David Calister*, I defined a command which insert all the arguments in a box and return the height of the box, and also defined a new lenght (called `MyLen`).

The following code,

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\zz[3]{\sbox0{\ensuremath{#1#2#3}}\the\ht0}
\newlength{\MyLen}

\begin{document}
\zz{1}{2}{\frac{3}{4}}
\zz{1}{2}{3}
\end{document}
```

results into

[image]

Well Done so far!

Then, I'd like to set `MyLen` to be such result, using

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\zz[3]{\sbox0{\ensuremath{#1#2#3}}\the\ht0}
\newlength{\MyLen}

\begin{document}
\zz{1}{2}{\frac{3}{4}}

\zz{1}{2}{3}

\settoheight\MyLen{\zz{1}{2}{\frac{3}{4}}}
\the\MyLen
\end{document}
```

but the result is wrong (the last value should be equal to the first one)

[image]

What is happening? Where is my mistake?

Comment: :-) you worried me for a bit there:-)  `\settoheight\MyLen{\zz{1}{2}{\frac{3}{4}}}`  measures the height of the output of `\zz` which is the string 8.44843pt and that has height 6.44444 same as 123 ;-)

Comment: so you can of course not use `\zz` and use `\settoheight\MyLen{$1  2 \frac{3}{4}$} ` as `\zz` and `\settoheight` have essentially the same definition except one uses box 0 and one uses `\@tempboxa` for measuring

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes Sir! you're right again! Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\newcommand\zz[3]{%
\sbox0{#1#2#3}%
\showthe\ht0
}
```

Comment: To whovever downvoted, would you care to say why? This does exactly what is asked in the question `\ht0` is the maximum height of the renderings of the three arguments.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I found your code very helpful, and a small tweak is almost working... I've updated the question. (Note that I change `\showthe\ht0` by `\the\ht0`, because your suggestion gave me compilation problems). :-)

Comment: @Dox `\showthe` is a debugging command like `\show` it stops with a fake error at that point and shows the value on the terminal, hit return and it continues, it is not intended for production code